# query to show selected options from multi select field in mysql

Tags: mysql, phpbb3

I am trying to get a query working that shows specific info from a mult-select-field that is part of a phpbb forum.

```
SELECT d.pf_firstname, d.pf_lastname, d.pf_specialism
FROM phpbb_profile_fields_data d
WHERE d.pf_lastname = 'Linssen'
```

The query above gives the following Result:

```
-- firstname: Pierre
-- lastname: Linssen 
-- pf_specialism: 1;3;8;10;12;15;16 (which are the selected options)
```

In another table the relation between the available options (0 to 18) 
and the related text is given.

[result of a "wrong" query, showing all these options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mytk.jpg)

The query I need should show: firstname and lastname of a user and **only** the specific options that that user (in this case: Linssen) has selected for a specific profile field (in this case: specialism).

So the result of the query should be something like

```
-- firstname: Pierre
-- lastname: Linssen
-- specialism: (1) Counseling ; (2) Executive Coaching ; (8) Oplossings gericht coachen; (10) Provocatief coachen ; (12) Sales coaching ; (15) Team coaching ; (16) Wandel coaching
```

How do I do that?

In order to support multi-language, profile fields values (TEXT) are stored in the _lang table, and the actual _data table only holds indexes to the lang table. So that you have, say, 3 stored in the data table, and then you map that to "Project Manager" in English or "Gestor de Proyectos" in Spanish...

2017-01-22: Thanks for input sofar still struggling to get the query to work.
Please find below the three tables with their relevant content.

**phpbb_profile_lang has the following relevant fields**
-- field_id (41)
-- lang_id (2)
-- lang_name (specialisme)

**phpbb_profile_fields_data has the following relevant fields**
-- user_id (90)
-- pf_voornaam (Pierre)
-- pf_achternaam (Linssen)
-- pf_specialisme (1;3;8;10;12;15;16)

**phpbb_profile_fields_lang has the following relevant fields**
-- field_id (41)
-- lang_id (2)
-- option_id (0) lang_value (Business Coaching)
-- option_id (1) lang_value (Counseling)
-- option_id (2) lang_value (Executive Coaching)
-- option_id (3) lang_value (Holistische Coaching)
-- ...............................................
-- ...............................................
-- option_id (17) lang_value (Zingeving)
-- option_id (18) lang_value (Overige)

Comment: are the `specialism`s all in one row semicolon separated? or are they in separate rows?

Comment: Is there going to be a single row for each name or multiple rows?

Comment: the specialisms (like coaching, counseling, training) themselves are each in a seperate row, where each specialism has a unique option_id

Comment: For a user is phpbb_profile_fields_data a single row per pf_specialisme or a single row with all of the pf_specialisme?

Comment: phpbb_profile_fields_data is a table that contains all the users (and Piere Linssen is one of them). And the table also holds all the chosen options for the defined multi selectable fields. For "specialisme" Pierre Linssen has chosen the options (1;3;8;10;12;15 and 16). All the 19 (0-18) available options that could be chosen for "specialisme" are listed in the table phpbb_profile_fields_lang.

Answer (score 0):

Your query to join the tables would look like this:

```
select pf_voornaam, pf_lastname, lang_value
from phpbb_profile_fields_data pfd
inner join phpbb_profile_fields_lang pfl on pfl.feld_id = pfd.pf_specialisme
inner join phpbb_profile_lang pl on pfl.lang_id = pl.lang_id;
```

If you have control of the schema, I would strongly recommend to change phpbb_profile_lang.lang_id to be the primary key field_id and remove the lang_id - this is redundant based on the data you've shown.

Based on your example, I have used the following query:

```
select pf_voornaam, pf_achternaam, pf_specialisme, lang_value
from phpbb_profile_fields_data pfd
inner join phpbb_profile_fields_lang pfl on pfl.field_id = pfd.pf_specialisme
inner join phpbb_profile_lang pl on pfl.lang_id = pl.lang_id;
```

The result is shown in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QhyZ.jpg)

Comment: in phpbb there are 3 relevant tables to be considered: phpbb_profile_fields_data // phpbb_profile_fields_lang // phpbb_profile_lang

Comment: Without seeing the contents of each table I am unable to determine which is the association table (if any), but you should be able to take my example and find which table it is and replace the first inner join's information  with that one

Comment: 2017-01-22: I added the initial question with the missing table-info.

Comment: Assuming phpbb_profile_fields_data contains a single row per pf_specialisme, this query should do the trick.

Comment: I really cannot help you further without seeing the schema and an example dataset for the phpbb_profile_fields_data table. Can you post the actual create statements? Can you determine at WHICH point the query breaks? Start without the joins then add the joins in one by one to see which one is breaking.

Answer (score 0):

With all the relevant input here and with help of "Javiexin", the following mysqli-based php-script with the various included mysql-queries did the trick. I am open to any suggestions to further improve the queries and script.

Here is a [link to a result page](http://www.tukhut.nl/test4/fetch_finalC.php).

```
<?php

/*Open connection to our database. */

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "perspec1", "FLeur0798!", "perspec1");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

/* check if server is alive */
if (mysqli_ping($link)) {
printf ("A: Our connection is OK!<br/><br/>");
} else {
printf ("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
}

/* First MYSQL query */
$sql = "SELECT d.pf_voornaam, d.pf_achternaam, d.pf_specialisme FROM phpbb_profile_fields_data d WHERE d.pf_achternaam = 'Linssen'";

if (!$sql) { echo "Error: ".mysqli_error(); die(); 
} else {
    printf ("B: First query is successful!<br/><br/>");
}

        if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql))
        {
            echo "<table>";
            //header
            echo "<tr><td>Voornaam</td>";
            echo "<td>Achternaam</td>";
            echo "<td>Specialisme</td></tr>";
            //data  
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
            {
            echo "<tr><td>{$row[0]}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$row[1]}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$row[2]}</td></tr>";
            } 
                echo "</table><br/>";
        }

/* Second MYSQL query */
$query2 = mysqli_query($link, $sql );

if (!$query2) { echo "Error: ".mysqli_error(); die(); 
} else {
printf ("C: Second query is successful!<br/><br/>");
}

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2))
$selected_opts = explode (";", $row['pf_specialisme']);
foreach ($selected_opts as $selected_opt) echo "$selected_opt <br/>";
echo "<br/>";
$selected_opts_string = implode(', ', $selected_opts);

$sql3 = "SELECT fl.option_id, fl.lang_value FROM phpbb_profile_fields f,     phpbb_profile_fields_lang fl WHERE f.field_id = fl.field_id AND f.field_name = 'specialisme' AND fl.lang_id = 1 AND fl.option_id IN ($selected_opts_string) ORDER BY fl.option_id ASC";
$query3 = mysqli_query($link, $sql3 );

if (!$sql3) { echo "Error: ".mysqli_error(); die(); 
} else {
    printf ("D: Third query is successful!<br/><br/>");
}

if (!$query3) { echo "Error: ".mysqli_error(); die(); }

echo "<table>";
while( $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query3) )
{
echo "<tr><td>$result[option_id]</td>";
echo "<td>$result[lang_value]</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($link);

?>
```